# Missing required parameters for [Route: cart-update]

Tags: php, laravel

I cannot solve this error that throws me, I use Laravel 6

> Missing required parameters for [Route: cart-update] [URI: cart/update/{product}/{quantity?}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\final\resources\views\store\cart.blade.php)

web:

```
Route::get('cart/update/{product}/{quantity?}', [
'as' => 'cart-update',
'uses' => 'CartController@update'
```

]);

CartController:

```
public function update(Product $product, $quantity)
{
    $cart = \Session::get('cart');
    $cart[$product->slug]->quantity = $quantity;
    \Session::put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('cart-show');
}
```

.blade.php

```
data-href="{{ route('cart-update', $item->slug) }}"
```

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>   Missing required parameters for [Route: cart-update] [URI: cart/update/{product}/{quantity?}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\final\resources\views\store\cart.blade.php)

https://flareapp.io/share/qm1eNzmd#F54

I can't solve the problem, help please

Comment: Add the parameter name `data-href="{{ route('cart-update', ['product' => $item->slug]) }}"`

Comment: thanks for the help but still giving me the same error :(

Comment: Are you sure that `$item->slug` is not null? Try hardcoding the value `{{ route('cart-update', ['product' => 1])`. Also... Why you are using model binding with a slug? It is the model primary key?

Comment: Your route required two parameter `product` & `quantity`, but you passed only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In the route you are declaring quantity `cart/update/{product}/{quantity?}` as optional, but in the `store` method not.

You have to do this so I don't give you the error:

```
public function update(Product $product, $quantity = null)
{
    $cart = \Session::get('cart');
    $cart[$product->slug]->quantity = $quantity;
    \Session::put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('cart-show');
}
```

Note that `$quantity` will now be `null` if you do not pass both parameters. So you'll have to validate that in your business logic.

Comment: thanks for the help but still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try sending two parameters like this:

```
data-href="{{ route('cart-update', [$item, $item->quantity]) }}"
```